# Python package for efficient weighted shortest path finding

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

My problem is to find the shortest path between `u` and `v` which are nodes in a directed graph and the edges of the graph have weights.

I have tried using [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html), but it is too slow (average 50ms on a graph of 37202 nodes and 79264 edges).

[igraph](https://igraph.org/) does not seem to provide an API for *weighted* shortest path.

Is there any other tools available?

---

Here's the code I'm using. (`test_graph.txt` is just the graph definition, and `test_nodes.txt` contains nodes for test)

```py
import networkx as nx
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

G = nx.DiGraph()
with open("test_graph.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        l = l.strip().split("\t")
        G.add_edge(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), length=float(l[2]))

nodes = [int(i) for i in open("test_nodes.txt")]
N = 1000
for _ in tqdm(range(N)):
    u, v = random.sample(nodes, 2)
    cnt = 0
    total = 0
    try:
        t = time.time()
        nx.shortest_path(G, u, v, weight="length")
        total += time.time() - t
        cnt += 1
    except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
        pass
print(f"{cnt/N*100:.2f} found, average {total/cnt:.6f}s")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Oleksii , `igraph` can be used for my problem.

However, the official documentation is not very clear. I give a minimal example below as a reference for anyone who may have the same problem.

```py
import igraph

# define edges and their weights
edges=[(0,1),(1,2),(0,2)]
weights=[1,1,3]

# create directed graph
# use directed=False for undirected graph
G=igraph(edges, directed=True)

# set edge attributes
G.es['weight']=weights

# find shortest path from 0 to 2
# use predefined 'weight' attribute as weights
# the result is [[0,1],[1,2]]
path=G.get_shorted_paths(0,2,weights='weight')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try method `get_shortest_paths` of the `igraph` library. It has the `weights` parameter. You can find documentation [here](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#get_shortest_paths).